# Progress Dialog doesn't appear

Tags: android, sms, progressdialog

Let me clarify it first that I am still a very amateur android developer just started about a week ago by learning from the tutorials on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

So if my code appear to be ugly forgive me for that..

Now the actual problem - "PROGRESS DIALOG DOESN'T APPEAR" - but the rest of the code is working fine. It is sending the SMS and I am receiving them, just facing problem with PROGRESS DIALOG.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Context context;

public final static String EXTRA_NUMBER = "com.example.myfirstapp.NUMBER";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    if (!isOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Internet Access..Cannot Send SMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        ProgressDialog prgDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Free Sms","Sending SMS..Please Wait..!!",true);           
        EditText editTextNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_number);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String number = editTextNum.getText().toString();
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        try {
            prgDialog.dismiss();
            String msgreciever = number;
            String testMessage = message;
            SmsSender.sendMessage(msgreciever, testMessage);                
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            editTextNum.setText("");
            editText.setText("");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            prgDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sending Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: @nandeesh what did u do?

Comment: I removed the imports, from the code

Comment: anyone can edit the post, if you have enough reputation

Comment: @TapanDesai : I removed the 'java' tag. I do this when I see a post which is only related to Android. Even though you program for Android with Java, don't put a 'java' tag on your question unless it is a specific Java question. Many Java programmers don't program for Android and don't understand how Android works.

Comment: @tapan desai: You want progress dialog when msg is sending right ??? if u want that then tell me i will solve you problem...

Comment: @HardikgiriGoswami yes i want to exactly what you said..

Comment: @TapanDesai: I Add the comment and do the modification in your code so now it will work for you.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Tapan Actually  You have to use the "Thread" or "Runnable" for this kind of operation... so in the "else" part of your code put this modified code which uses the Thread.. so it will definitly work for you....

```
EditText editTextNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_number);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
final String number = editTextNum.getText().toString();
final String message = editText.getText().toString();
final ProgressDialog prgDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Free Sms","Sending SMS..Please Wait..!!",true);
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            SmsSender.sendMessage(number, message);
            prgDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
t.start();
editTextNum.setText("");
editText.setText("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

`prgDialog.dismiss` immediately after `prgDialog.show.`

That is the reason it is not showing up.

Edit:
Add below code instead of dismiss, this should remove dialog after 3 seconds

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) 
 {
      @Override
       public void onTick(long l) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onFinish(){
             prgDialog.dismiss();
       };
 }.start();
```

Comment: but the application freezes for a while when i click in send button and then it shows the Toast msg that the "Message was sent successfully"

Comment: no i didnt remove it..its the same code which i have pasted here.

Comment: remove the dismiss call then you can see the dialog

Comment: but then the dialog will be constantly displayed. isn't it?

Comment: you will have to put a timer and dismiss it later

Comment: can u tell me how to do that?

Comment: pls be there for sometime.. i am trying that.

Comment: its still the same problem.. application freezes for a while when clicking on send button then it directly pops up the Toast "Msg send successfully."